# Access each (x, y) within Multipart gdf.geometry.interiors

Tags: python, geopandas, interior-ring

How would I access each x, y coordinate within a GeoDataFrame.geometry.interior?

With:

```py
for ids, row in gdf.iterrows():
    for interior in row.geometry.interiors:
        for oring in list(interior.coords):
            print(oring)
            break
```

you would get something like:

```
(281755.0807502931, 6242820.412169201)
(281849.4055729074, 6242837.953621909)
...
(282022.0423603806, 6242795.454011634)
(282182.65706839535, 6242633.633094577)
```

This is a `LINEARRING`. I want to perform some function with each coordinate but don't know how to access it.
If I now go:

```py
for ids, row in rd_diff.iterrows():
    for interiors in row.geometry.interiors:
        for oring in list(interiors.coords):
            for x, y in oring:
                print(x, y)
                break
```

I get:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
```

How can I access each coordinate within a `LINEARRING`?

Comment: You have already accessed each coordinate. Each line in the output is a coordinate.

Comment: Sorry; I was not clear. I want to perform some-function with each (x, y) . I can access the entire LINEARRING. How do I now extract each coordinate pair ---as a seperate entity--- from a LINEARRING?

Comment: The result is a simple Python list of coordinates

Comment: @gene; If it were a list would `for u in i: print(u) break` ---following `for i in interior.coords:` not produce one (x, y) pair? The print statement is the entire LINEARRING. How do I extract each coordinte pair from a LINEARRING?

Comment: Look the answer below

Comment: Check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287314/29431).

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz; that is what I have. How do I now iterate a LINEARRING and extract each (x, y) pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exterior = [(2, 8), (7, 8), (7, 3), (2, 3), (2, 8)]
interior = [(4, 7), (4, 5), (6, 5), (6, 7), (4, 7)]
poly = Polygon(exterior, holes=[interior])
# numbers of holes
len(poly.interiors)
1
# therefore
print(list(poly.interiors[0].coords))
[(4.0, 7.0), (4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0), (4.0, 7.0)]
#
print(poly.interiors[0].coords[:])
[(4.0, 7.0), (4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0), (4.0, 7.0)]
```

And

```
for coord in poly.interiors[0].coords[:]:
     print(coord)
(4.0, 7.0)
(4.0, 5.0)
(6.0, 5.0)
(6.0, 7.0)
(4.0, 7.0)
# or
# first coordinate
poly.interiors[0].coords[:][0]
(4.0, 7.0)
# second coordinate
poly.interiors[0].coords[:][1]
(4.0, 5.0)
....

type(poly.interiors[0])
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.LinearRing'>
```

### New

There is a problem with your solution: oring is a simple 1D list therefore you can iterate iterate over a list by one value

```
for i in (1,2):
    print(i,)
1,2
```

But not by more:

```
  for x,y in (1,2):
       print(x,y)
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The solution is (destructuring the list as variables)

```
  x,y = (1,2) # len = 2
```

Therefore, with `geometry.interior` as a list of Polygons

```
exterior = [(2, 8), (7, 8), (7, 3), (2, 3), (2, 8)]
interior = [(4, 7), (4, 5), (6, 5), (6, 7), (4, 7)]
interior2 = [(3, 5), (3, 4), (4, 4), (4, 5), (3, 5)]
poly = Polygon(exterior, holes=[interior,interior2])
```

To extract individual x,y

```
 # first coordinate of the first interior polygon
 x,y = poly.interiors[0].coords[:][0]
 print(x,y)
 x: 4.0 y: 7.0
 # third coordinate of the second interior polygon
 x,y = poly.interiors[1].coords[:][2]
 print("x:",x,"y:",y)
 x: 4.0 y: 4.0

# all coordinates
for i, interior in enumerate(poly.interiors):
    print("interior: ",i)
    for oring in list(interior.coords):
        x,y = oring # oring is a list of floats
        print("oring:",oring,"x:",x,"y: ",y)
interior:  0
oring:(4.0, 7.0) x: 4.0 y:  7.0
oring:(4.0, 5.0) x: 4.0 y:  5.0
oring:(6.0, 5.0) x: 6.0 y:  5.0
oring:(6.0, 7.0) x: 6.0 y:  7.0
oring:(4.0, 7.0) x: 4.0 y:  7.0
interior:  1
oring:(3.0, 5.0) x: 3.0 y:  5.0
oring:(3.0, 4.0) x: 3.0 y:  4.0
oring:(4.0, 4.0) x: 4.0 y:  4.0
oring: 4.0, 5.0) x: 4.0 y:  5.0
oring:(3.0, 5.0) x: 3.0 y:  5.0
```

To extract lists of x and y

```
for i, interior in enumerate(poly.interiors):
    ppx, ppy = zip(*interior.coords)
    print("interior:",i,"ppx:",ppx,"ppy:",ppy)

interior: 0 ppx: (4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 4.0) ppy: (7.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0)
interior: 1 ppx: (3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0) ppy: (5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0)
```

Comment: after `for coord in interior[0].coords[:]: print(coord)` -> `TypeError: 'LinearRing' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Then try with `for coord in list(poly.interior.coords):` because  coordinates slicing has been introduced in the version 1.2.14.

Comment: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object`

Comment: What is your shapely version ?

Comment: you are being very patient with me. thank you. `shapely=1.8.0` It might be the `geometry.interior` is `Multipart` ---does this mean: more than one interior polygon? If so iteration is not supported. How does one extract a (x, y) pair then?

Comment: Look at New in my answer

Comment: You have been extremely helpful. I'm not able to extract each coordinate pair ---one after the other. If I go: `for co in zip(ppx, ppy): print(co)` after `ppx, ppy = zip(*interior.coords)` I get the first pair in BOTH interiors. I want to iterate each interior and then each coordinate pair in that interior. And then the next interior; and so forth. I must be missing something obvious because I am unable too.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. ---I got the full solution from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433135/iterate-multipart-gdf-geometry-interiors)